# MySQL system date change impact

Tags: mysql, timestamp, datetime

I can't find an answer for this problem.

If I have in my database data of datatypes like date and timestamp. Can the change of system date affect this saved data ? I mean, can these **existing** timestamp and date values be changed after the change of system date ?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the system date or the system time does not change values stored in tables.

Existing values *can* be changed using an UPDATE statement, though.

Datetime and timestamp columns behave differently on retrieval.

```
create table tz_test (
  ts timestamp not null,
  dt datetime not null
);

insert into tz_test values (current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

select * from tz_test;

ts                   dt
--
2013-06-27 09:46:14  2013-06-27 09:46:14
```

Set a session timezone, and compare.

```
set time_zone = '-8:00';
select * from tz_test;

ts                   dt
--
2013-06-27 05:46:14  2013-06-27 09:46:14  
           ^^
```

[Timezone support in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)

Docs show you how to change both client and server timezones for testing. You *have* to read that.

Comment: and if I changed the timezone and then made a SELECT. Will the values inside the select transformed using that timezone or displayed as they were in database before ?